# Update a table row based on another table insert using a TRIGGER?

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design, triggers, plpgsql

I'm a little bit stuck on this. I am using a trigger so that when a new data entry is inserted into VISITED, it should update the visits attribute in the table called places. However, I don't know how to make it so that only that inserted row's visits is updated in the table PLACES. What happens is the entire visits column gets updated in PLACES for every place that is also in VISITED...I tried using

```
SET NEW.visits = visits + 1
```

But then I receive an error that new is not recognized...any ideas/suggestions ? :(

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_visits() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $BODY$
 BEGIN
   UPDATE places
   SET visits = visits + 1
   FROM visited WHERE(places.name = visited.name AND 
places.borough = visited.borough);
   RETURN NEW;
 END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;


CREATE TRIGGER trigger_visits AFTER INSERT ON visited
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE
log_visits();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update only rows to which `new` is pointing:

```
create or replace function log_visits() 
returns trigger as $body$
begin
    update places
    set visits = visits + 1
    where places.name = new.name 
    and places.borough = new.borough;
    return null;
end;
$body$
language plpgsql;
```

Btw, a trigger after insert should return `null` (though any return value is ignored).

Test it in [DbFiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=0653bae7d3a185bab87c97d7b6bcada1)

Comment: thank you!!!!!!!! was it me returning NEW that was causing the entire column to be updated rather than just the newly inserted row?

Comment: No, the problem was in the `where` clause, you should use `new` to point the row which was inserted. Without this all rows from `visited` were taken into account.